# WSO2 API manager: ActiveDirectory as second user store

Tags: wso2

I have create my configuration file for the second user store here: /opt/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/deployment/server/userstores i named it with the name of my domain (sub_dom_local.xml my domain is sub.dom.local)
and I set as primary user store a jdbc store.
When I try to login with a domain user name I obtain this error:
[2014-06-25 10:48:39,828] ERROR -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin}

I am sure than I have insert the correct username and password, I enabled the debug loggr and I see in the log that the Authentication procedure connected to the Active directory and retrieve all the information.
If I insert a wrong password i do not have the error but I have the information for the wrong password.
Could you help me?
Thanks Jack

Comment: Try define 2ndry usertsore via managementconsole-->usertsore mene

Comment: I do It. FIrst I add via managmentconsole and after that I modified some parpmeters by hand in the file Thanks Jack

Comment: I enalbed the row number in the log and I obtainf this information: [2014-06-25 12:07:46,990] ERROR -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin}L: 135
The error is in the row 135
I use wso2am version 1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

When the ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager is enabled it seems we need to enable GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled property in Authorization manager as follows in user manager configuration

```
`<AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
<Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
<Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
<Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">true</Property>
</AuthorizationManager>
```

`

Otherwise it is throwing the exception you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Ajanthan,I try to modify my configuration but it does not working.
File:<Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property><Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property<Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property><Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property><Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property><Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property><Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property><Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property"><Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">true</Property><Property name="WriteGroups">false</Property>
Tks Jack

Comment: It should be added inside AuthorizationManager tag at the end of the user-mgt.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
...
 <Property name="MemberOfAttribute"/>
...
</UserStoreManager>
```

You do not specify the MemberOfAttribute.
Matteo

Comment: I try it, and without MemberOfAttribute specification it is working
Thanks.